# Null Pointer exception - Robotium Unit test

Tags: java, android, eclipse, nullpointerexception, robotium

I am trying to perform unittest using robotium ... every time i try i get a null pointer exception ... Everything is fine until the app loads and then the exception occurs ... In the tutorial it is said that this error would occur but the solution was not clear .. kindly help .. the code is as follows :

```
package com.testCalculator;
import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;  
import com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class TestApk extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 {
    private static final String LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_FULL_CLASSNAME = "com.calculator.Main";

    private static Class launcherActivityClass;
    static {
        try {
            launcherActivityClass = Class.forName(LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_FULL_CLASSNAME);
        } 
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public TestApk() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        super(launcherActivityClass);
    }

    private Solo solo;
    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
    }

    public void testDisplayBlackBox() {
        // Enter any integer/decimal value for first edit-field, we are writing 10
        solo.clearEditText(0);
        solo.enterText(0, "10");
        // Enter any integer/decimal value for first edit-field, we are writing 20
        solo.clearEditText(1);
        solo.enterText(1, "20");
        // Tap on Multiply button
        solo.clickOnButton("Multiply");
        //Assert that the correct resultant of 10 x 20 is returned
        assertTrue("Problem asserting multiply", solo.searchText("200"));
    }

    @Override
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        solo.finishOpenedActivities();
    }
}
```

The Blackbox testing Failure Trace:

```
TestApk (2)
samsung-samsung_sm_n900a-a0964e35
com.testCalculator.TestApk
testDisplayBlackBox (com.testCalculator.TestApk) [samsung-samsung_sm_n900a-a0964e35]
java.lang.NullPointerException

at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.ViewFetcher.getNonDecorViews(ViewFetcher.java:163)

at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.ViewFetcher.getAllViews(ViewFetcher.java:85)

at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.ViewFetcher.getViews(ViewFetcher.java:194)

at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.ViewFetcher.getCurrentViews(ViewFetcher.java:312)

at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.ViewFetcher.getCurrentViews(ViewFetcher.java:299)

at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Searcher.searchFor(Searcher.java:123)

at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Waiter.waitForView(Waiter.java:105)

at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Waiter.waitForAndGetView(Waiter.java:348)

at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo.enterText(Solo.java:1290)

at com.testCalculator.TestApk.testDisplayBlackBox(TestApk.java:29)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)

at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)

at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTest(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:192)

at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)

at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)

at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)

at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1741)
```

Log cat output :

```
07-18 10:36:28.084: I/dalvikvm(31894): Enabling JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 8...
07-18 10:36:28.134: I/TestRunner(31894): started: testDisplayBlackBox(com.testCalculator.TestApk)
07-18 10:36:28.154: I/TestRunner(31894): finished: testDisplayBlackBox(com.testCalculator.TestApk)
07-18 10:36:28.154: I/TestRunner(31894): passed: testDisplayBlackBox(com.testCalculator.TestApk)
07-18 10:36:28.924: I/dalvikvm(31977): Enabling JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 8...
07-18 10:36:28.964: I/TestRunner(31977): started: testDisplayBlackBox(com.testCalculator.TestApk)
07-18 10:36:29.014: W/ApplicationPackageManager(31977): getCSCPackageItemText()
07-18 10:36:29.124: I/Adreno-EGL(31977): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
07-18 10:36:29.124: I/Adreno-EGL(31977): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.07
07-18 10:36:29.124: I/Adreno-EGL(31977): Build Date: 01/22/14 Wed
07-18 10:36:29.124: I/Adreno-EGL(31977): Local Branch: base_au149_adreno_au169_patches
07-18 10:36:29.124: I/Adreno-EGL(31977): Remote Branch: 
07-18 10:36:29.124: I/Adreno-EGL(31977): Local Patches: 
07-18 10:36:29.124: I/Adreno-EGL(31977): Reconstruct Branch: 
07-18 10:36:29.164: D/OpenGLRenderer(31977): Enabling debug mode 0
07-18 10:36:29.254: V/RenderScript(31977): Application requested CPU execution
07-18 10:36:29.254: V/RenderScript(31977): 0x78878260 Launching thread(s), CPUs 4
07-18 10:36:29.274: E/dalvikvm(31977): Could not find class 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity', referenced from method com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Waiter.getSupportFragment
07-18 10:36:29.274: W/dalvikvm(31977): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 21 (Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity;) in Lcom/jayway/android/robotium/solo/Waiter;
07-18 10:36:29.274: D/dalvikvm(31977): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x0009
07-18 10:36:29.274: I/dalvikvm(31977): Could not find method android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager, referenced from method com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Waiter.getSupportFragment
07-18 10:36:29.274: W/dalvikvm(31977): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 26: Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity;.getSupportFragmentManager ()Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentManager;
07-18 10:36:29.274: D/dalvikvm(31977): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0010
07-18 10:36:29.274: I/dalvikvm(31977): Could not find method android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager, referenced from method com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Waiter.getSupportFragment
07-18 10:36:29.274: W/dalvikvm(31977): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 26: Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity;.getSupportFragmentManager ()Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentManager;
07-18 10:36:29.274: D/dalvikvm(31977): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0019
07-18 10:36:29.274: W/dalvikvm(31977): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;)
07-18 10:36:29.274: W/dalvikvm(31977): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;)
07-18 10:36:29.774: W/System.err(31977): java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: mViews
07-18 10:36:29.784: W/System.err(31977):    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:596)
07-18 10:36:29.784: W/System.err(31977):    at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.ViewFetcher.getWindowDecorViews(ViewFetcher.java:382)
07-18 10:36:29.784: W/System.err(31977):    at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.ViewFetcher.getAllViews(ViewFetcher.java:83)
07-18 10:36:29.784: W/System.err(31977):    at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.ViewFetcher.getViews(ViewFetcher.java:194)
07-18 10:36:29.784: W/System.err(31977):    at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.ViewFetcher.getCurrentViews(ViewFetcher.java:312)
07-18 10:36:29.784: W/System.err(31977):    at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.ViewFetcher.getCurrentViews(ViewFetcher.java:299)
07-18 10:36:29.784: W/System.err(31977):    at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Searcher.searchFor(Searcher.java:123)
07-18 10:36:29.784: W/System.err(31977):    at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Waiter.waitForView(Waiter.java:105)
07-18 10:36:29.784: W/System.err(31977):    at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Waiter.waitForAndGetView(Waiter.java:348)
07-18 10:36:29.784: W/System.err(31977):    at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo.clearEditText(Solo.java:1339)
07-18 10:36:29.784: W/System.err(31977):    at com.testCalculator.TestApk.testDisplayBlackBox(TestApk.java:27)
07-18 10:36:29.784: W/System.err(31977):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-18 10:36:29.794: W/System.err(31977):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-18 10:36:29.794: W/System.err(31977):    at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
07-18 10:36:29.794: W/System.err(31977):    at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)
07-18 10:36:29.794: W/System.err(31977):    at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTest(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:192)
07-18 10:36:29.794: W/System.err(31977):    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)
07-18 10:36:29.794: W/System.err(31977):    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:115)
07-18 10:36:29.794: W/System.err(31977):    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:133)
07-18 10:36:29.794: W/System.err(31977):    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:118)
07-18 10:36:29.794: W/System.err(31977):    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
07-18 10:36:29.794: W/System.err(31977):    at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
07-18 10:36:29.794: W/System.err(31977):    at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
07-18 10:36:29.794: W/System.err(31977):    at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)
07-18 10:36:29.794: W/System.err(31977):    at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1741)
07-18 10:36:29.994: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(31977): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
07-18 10:36:30.734: I/TestRunner(31977): failed: testDisplayBlackBox(com.testCalculator.TestApk)
07-18 10:36:30.734: I/TestRunner(31977): ----- begin exception -----
07-18 10:36:30.734: I/TestRunner(31977): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-18 10:36:30.734: I/TestRunner(31977):    at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.ViewFetcher.getNonDecorViews(ViewFetcher.java:163)
07-18 10:36:30.734: I/TestRunner(31977):    at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.ViewFetcher.getAllViews(ViewFetcher.java:85)
07-18 10:36:30.734: I/TestRunner(31977):    at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.ViewFetcher.getViews(ViewFetcher.java:194)
07-18 10:36:30.734: I/TestRunner(31977):    at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.ViewFetcher.getCurrentViews(ViewFetcher.java:312)
07-18 10:36:30.734: I/TestRunner(31977):    at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.ViewFetcher.getCurrentViews(ViewFetcher.java:299)
07-18 10:36:30.734: I/TestRunner(31977):    at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Searcher.searchFor(Searcher.java:123)
07-18 10:36:30.734: I/TestRunner(31977):    at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Waiter.waitForView(Waiter.java:105)
07-18 10:36:30.734: I/TestRunner(31977):    at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Waiter.waitForAndGetView(Waiter.java:348)
07-18 10:36:30.734: I/TestRunner(31977):    at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo.clearEditText(Solo.java:1339)
07-18 10:36:30.734: I/TestRunner(31977):    at com.testCalculator.TestApk.testDisplayBlackBox(TestApk.java:27)
07-18 10:36:30.734: I/TestRunner(31977):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-18 10:36:30.734: I/TestRunner(31977):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-18 10:36:30.734: I/TestRunner(31977):    at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
07-18 10:36:30.734: I/TestRunner(31977):    at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)
07-18 10:36:30.734: I/TestRunner(31977):    at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTest(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:192)
07-18 10:36:30.734: I/TestRunner(31977):    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:134)
07-18 10:36:30.734: I/TestRunner(31977):    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:115)
07-18 10:36:30.734: I/TestRunner(31977):    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:133)
07-18 10:36:30.734: I/TestRunner(31977):    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:118)
07-18 10:36:30.734: I/TestRunner(31977):    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:124)
07-18 10:36:30.734: I/TestRunner(31977):    at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191)
07-18 10:36:30.734: I/TestRunner(31977):    at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176)
07-18 10:36:30.734: I/TestRunner(31977):    at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)
07-18 10:36:30.734: I/TestRunner(31977):    at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1741)
07-18 10:36:30.734: I/TestRunner(31977): ----- end exception -----
07-18 10:36:30.734: I/TestRunner(31977): finished: testDisplayBlackBox(com.testCalculator.TestApk)
```

Console Output :

```
Android Launch!
[2014-07-18 10:36:09 - TestCalculator] adb is running normally.
[2014-07-18 10:36:09 - TestCalculator] Performing android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner JUnit launch
[2014-07-18 10:36:09 - TestCalculator] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2014-07-18 10:36:11 - TestCalculator] Uploading TestCalculator.apk onto device 'a0964e35'
[2014-07-18 10:36:11 - TestCalculator] Installing TestCalculator.apk...
[2014-07-18 10:36:16 - TestCalculator] Success!
[2014-07-18 10:36:16 - TestCalculator] Project dependency found, installing: AndroidCalculator
[2014-07-18 10:36:16 - AndroidCalculator] Uploading AndroidCalculator.apk onto device 'a0964e35'
[2014-07-18 10:36:16 - AndroidCalculator] Installing AndroidCalculator.apk...
[2014-07-18 10:36:27 - AndroidCalculator] Success!
[2014-07-18 10:36:27 - TestCalculator] Launching instrumentation android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner on a0964e35
[2014-07-18 10:36:28 - TestCalculator] Sending test information to Eclipse
[2014-07-18 10:36:31 - TestCalculator] Test run finished
```

Comment: Post your logcat output.

Comment: I have added both logcat,console and junit outputs..

Comment: solo.clearEditText(0); .. sorry i uploaded the different code .. i corrected it ..

Comment: I don't see where you initialize `solo`. I see its declaration and I see a method that would initialize it, but I don't see you calling that method anywhere (e.g. `setUp()`). This would mean solo is null.

Comment: yup .. thanks .. i will correct it and get back to you ..

Comment: If it works let me know and I will post that as an answer.

Comment: Nope it doesnt... Calling setUp() or initialing solo within testDisplay .. niether works ...

The tutorial suggested this : 
We can solve this issue by following any of the suggestions below:
1. Create another TestProject & eclipse will automatically get selected resources(for the new one) & not
show error for second created Test Project(we can use the second one for our work)
OR
2. First create an Android Project (we can also use Android Sample application bundled with Android SDK),
run it, then create Test Project will not show error

Comment: no it refers to the mainActivity that i am testing.. its not null

Comment: I won't be able to help you with that because I don't see a mainactivity in the code you provided, or an onCreate method which would be starting your activity.

Comment: This is a unit test file .. MainActivity.java is in another project .. but thanks for the help .. ill try figuring it out

Comment: What does you method getNonDecorViews() do? it's it is this method which throws the NullPointerException. And seeing your log you already call on solo.ViewFetcher before, so it sould not be null until then so what is null might be in getNonDecorViews() and not before.

Comment: I haven't used it .. probably something internal .. i have searched online and the working solution seems to be to update robotium .. ill try that ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an old version of Robotium. Please update to 5.2.1 and you will not have this problem.

https://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/Downloads?tm=2

Comment: Yup .. thnaks .. !! .. i got the solution earlier but forgot to put up the answer ..

Answer (score 1):

Well .. That actually worked ... 
Solution : Update Robotium to latest Version .. currently 5.1 ...